# Understanding templates defined inside templates (C++)

Tags: c++, templates

According to my understanding, the following two programs should be effectively identical, but the second fails to compile. *Note that in this simplified example, the nesting is obviously useless, but it's necessary in the original context.*

**Version 1:** works as expected

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                         
template<typename Value>                                                                                                                 
struct Anything {                                                                                                                        
    Value value;                                                                                                                         
};                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                         
using A = const char *;                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                         
template<template<typename> class B>                                                                                                     
struct Inner {                                                                                                                           
    template<typename C>                                                                                                                 
    using type = B<C>;                                                                                                                   
};                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                         
template<template<typename> class B>                                                                                                     
struct OuterBase {                                                                                                                       
    B<A> b;                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                         
    void                                                                                                                                 
    print() { std::cout << "b: " << b.value << std::endl; }                                                                              
};                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                         
using Outer = OuterBase<Inner<Anything>::type>; // this version works                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                         
int                                                                                                                                      
main()                                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                        
    Outer outer;                                                                                                                         
    outer.b.value = "foo";                                                                                                               
    outer.print();                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                         
    return 0;                                                                                                                            
}
```

The compiler error in this version is "expected a template, got `TypeBox<A>::Inner<Anything>::type`".

**Version 2:** fails with compile error

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                         
template<typename Value>                                                                                                                 
struct Anything {                                                                                                                        
    Value value;                                                                                                                         
};                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                         
template<typename A>                                                                                                                     
struct TypeBox {                                                                                                                         
    template<template<typename> class B>                                                                                                 
    struct Inner {                                                                                                                       
        template<typename C>                                                                                                             
        using type = B<C>;                                                                                                               
    };                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                         
    template<template<typename> class B>                                                                                                 
    struct OuterBase {                                                                                                                   
        B<A> b;                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                         
        void                                                                                                                             
        print() { std::cout << "b: " << b.value << std::endl; }                                                                          
    };                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                         
    using Outer = OuterBase<Inner<Anything>::type>; // compile error here                                                                                      
};                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                         
int                                                                                                                                      
main()                                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                        
    using Box = typename TypeBox<const char *>::Outer;                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                         
    Box box;                                                                                                                             
    box.b.value = "foo";                                                                                                                 
    box.print();                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                         
    return 0;                                                                                                                            
}
```

I would expect the `TypeBox` struct to be transparent when resolving the types inside, but according to `gcc 12.2.1`, it isn't. Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in your second example is that a compiler cannot verify at the point of definition of the template that `Inner<Anything>::type` is really a class template or alias template. The problem is that `Inner` is a nested class template and you could in theory partially or explicitly specialize `Inner` for the given template argument later, so that `type` names e.g. a type.

So compilers tend to require that you place the `template` keyword before the template's name in such a case to state that it really is a template:

```
using Outer = OuterBase<Inner<Anything>::template type>;
```

My understanding is that technically there is nothing in the standard requiring this use of `template` though, but that this wasn't entirely clear. However, the standard did allow using the `template` keyword in this position, but will deprecate this allowance with C++23. If I am not mistaken compilers should also allow this without `template` keyword in the future even for previous standard revisions (as defect report). There wasn't ever really a point in performing this test.

See also [CWG issue 1478](https://wg21.link/cwg1478) and the paper proposing the deprecation [P1787R6](https://wg21.link/p1787r6).

Comment: If `Inner<Anything>` had been dependent on `typename A` in the outer template, wouldn't the `template` keyword then be necessary in that case? I guess I'm just curious how the proposed deprecation deals with that situation and maybe I should just read it myself.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts `Inner<Anything>` is dependent even if `Anything` isn't for the reason I gave at the beginning. Yes, compilers require this use of `template`, but that use will be deprecated and it seems that it was never really correct of compilers to require it anyway, see the linked CWG issue. The author of the paper proposing the deprecation, Davis Herring, also sometimes writes answers/comments around here and you can probably find more details on this in some of them.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Basically, the compiler doesn't have to care whether the dependent name refers to a template. The distinction between expressions and _types_ made with the `typename` keyword is only important because it affects parsing of the rest of the definition. There is no such issue when naming a template.

Comment: Did you mean to say that `Inner<Anything>::type` is dependent? That would align with the reason you gave, and I do already understand that part. Although I would argue that it is necessary to distinguish between a template and an expression due to the ambiguity caused by `<` (as in the binary operator) being a valid token following an expression.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, sorry, I meant `Inner<Anything>::type`. The use of `template` to disambiguate `<` is untouched. But in this case there is no `<` to disambiguate. The old use of `template` here wouldn't be for that purpose. When writing `Inner<Anything>::template type<int>`, then `template` is still allowed and required.